# Website popup is blocked in react native webview

Tags: react-native, authentication, webview

I want to integrate a website into a webview with react native.
Everything is fine until I want to login with facebook. When I press the "Login With Facebook" button, the webview become just a white screen and it is blocked.
This happens because when I press the login button, it tries to open a popup, but the popups are not enabled in react native webview.
So, my question is: how is possible to enable popups in webview? I just want my website to behave just like in a normal browser (like chrome, where everything is working fine), but inside my webview.
I use react native 0.55.

I read https://codeburst.io/webviews-and-social-authentication-with-react-native-cfecf96ac7d7 but didn't help me because I don't have access to the website source code.

Comment: Yeah, i need help with this too